# CTE to create Tree of objects

Tags: recursion, common-table-expression

I have two tables:
Folder, Files. 
Each table has 4 fields: 
ParentID, ID, Name, Type

I need to create a CTE in order to retrieve the entire tree in one shot, using T-SQL.
So far this is what I have done, but the recursion is not active yet.

I forgot to mention that inside a folder there may be one or more folders/files.

Comment: How do files relate to the folders? And what is the expected output (format) of the tree?

Comment: Always using ParentID. Both tables have ParentID field, which points to Folder.ID field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're using `NULL` for the `ParentID` items in the root the following should work:

```
WITH FilesAndFolders AS (
    SELECT ID AS FileID, 
           CAST(NULL AS int) AS FolderID, 
           ParentID, 
           Name, 
           [Type]
    FROM File
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(NULL AS int),
           ID, 
           ParentID, 
           Name, 
           [Type]
    FROM Folder
),
Tree AS (
    SELECT FileID, 
           FolderID, 
           Name, 
           [Type], 
           CAST('' AS nvarchar(MAX)) AS [Path]
    FROM FilesAndFolders
    WHERE ParentID IS NULL
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT FF.FileID, 
           FF.FolderID, 
           FF.Name, 
           FF.[Type], 
           T.[Path]+T.[Name]+'/'
    FROM FilesAndFolders FF
    JOIN Tree T ON T.FolderID = FF.ParentID
)
SELECT FileID, FolderID, [Path]+[Name] FullName, [Type]
FROM Tree
```

Comment: It works, thank you. I will probably remove the first select all and pass the parentID inside the first CTE to make it faster.

Comment: @Raffaeu, glad that it works. However, I don't understand what you mean with "remove the first select" - with the given data structure (e.g. files and folders in two different tables instead of one) I'm not sure how you want to significantly speed things up. Behind the scenes the "recursive" CTE isn't really recursing, but rather it has like a cursor on the created rows that can be used to join and therefore add more rows. Btw: greetings from the country you used to work in... ;)